# Asymptotic Analysis Inequalities

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity, inequalities

I have a problem understanding how the following inequalities highlighted in red were derived for this asymptotic analysis problem. Could someone explain the nature of these inequalities and how they came to be.

The following picture has the problem and solution.  The part highlighted in red is where I am having trouble understanding.

**Picture of the problem and solution**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Preparations

The part in the image above, above the red-marked section, is the very definition for the Big-Θ notation: "`f(n)` in `Θ(g(n))`", with

```
f(n) = (n + a)^b, b > 0        (+)
g(n) = n^b                     (++)
```

We'll repeat this inequality to simplify reference when showing that it holds below:

```
f(n) is in Θ(g(n)) with f(n) and g(n) as in (+) and (++), respectively

  <=>

c_1⋅n^b ≤ (n + a)^b ≤ c_2⋅n^b, for some positive constants c_1, c2     (*)
                               for n ≥ n_0, with n_0 constant > 0
```

Hence, we want to find some `c_1`, `c_2` and `n_0` such that `(*)` holds.

---

## Solution *(thoroughly explained)*

Now, since `b > 0`, we can prove that `(*)` holds if the follow two inequalities hold:

```
n + a ≥ k_1⋅n, for n > n_0      (i)
n + a ≤ k_2⋅n, for n > n_0      (ii)
```

for some positive constants `k_1` and `k_2` (which relates to `c_1` and `c_2` as `k_1^b = c_1` and `k_2^b = c_2`, respectively).

**Showing that `(ii)` holds**

We'll begin with showing that `(ii)` holds for some positive constant `k_1`. To do this, ***we can freely choose*** `n_0` such that `n_0 ≥ |a|` (since `a` is just a constant).

```
=> n ≥ |a| ≥ a, since n ≥ n_0 ≥ |a|

Hence:

n + a ≤ n + |a| ≤ n + n = 2⋅n, for n ≥ n_0 ≥ |a|   (II)
```

Now, with `(II)` we have showed that `(ii)` holds, with `k_1 = 2` and `n_0` being *any* value larger than `abs(a)`, `n_0 ≥ |a|`.

**Showing that `(i)` holds**

Now for showing `(i)`: we start by noting that the following inequality always holds:

```
n + a ≥ n - |a|                  (†)
```

(and is in fact equality if `a` is negative). Now, recall from above that `(II)` holds for any `n_0 ≥ |a|`. Alright, lets choose to fix our `n0` at `2⋅|a|` (note again: we can freely choose the constants we want to show that inequalities `(*)` holds).

```
Choose n_0 as n_0 = 2⋅|a|        (††)
```

Hence, from `(†)`:

```
n + a ≥ n - |a| ≥ n - n/2 = n/2  (†††)
                ^
                | 
               Why? Since from (††): |a| = n_0/2 < n/2, since n>n_0

We repeat (†††) without the middle stuff:  

n + a ≥ (1/2)⋅n, for n > n_0 = 2⋅|a|                (I)
```

And `(I)` now is simply `(i)` for `k_2 = 1/2` and `n_0 = 2⋅|a|`.

---

***Wrapping up***

We summarize:

```
(I) & (II) => (1/2)⋅n ≤ n + a ≤ 2⋅n

With b>0, this yields: 

   ((1/2)⋅n)^b ≤ (n + a)^b ≤ (2⋅n)^b                (**)
```

With `(**)`, we have showed that `(*)` holds, with

```
c_1 = k_1^b = (1/2)^b = 2^(-b)
c_2 = k_2^b = 2^b   (note that the solution you posted has an error here)
n_0 = 2⋅|a|
```

Hence, we have showed that `f(n)` as in `(+)` is in `Θ(g(n))`, with `g(n)` as in `(++)`.

---

Finally note that the choices of constants `c_1`, `c_2` (`k_1`, `k_2`) and `n_0` in `(*)` is not-unique: there exist infinitely many ways to show that `(*)` holds (if it does), or it exists none. The particular choices by the author of your solution just comes naturally in this case, but we could've chosen any number of other set of constants.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

Comment: @user5884813 Happy to help!